# Wordpress WPML: setup menu language switcher doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I can't choose a menu in this list... Nothing doesn't take account. I tried all menus, the result is the same. Do you have an idea?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question.

Comment: You would be much better off asking WPML support this question. You can also debug by activating a WP theme and see if it's your theme causing the issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you already tried reaching out to the WPML team about this? They should be able to help you out with this (that is assuming you have a active license since it's a paid plugin.) If not then you likely will need to debug this issue yourself (or hire a developer if you don't have the skills and/or the time to do it yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to using an older version of WPML with the latest version of WordPress (5.5), there was a similar issue preventing from adding language switcher because of a JS error:

https://wpml.org/errata/after-wordpress-5-5-it-is-not-possible-to-use-the-a-different-domain-per-language-option/

Update all WPML plugins to latest versions and try again. If that doesn't help then, as the good folks in the comments said: contact WPML support.